# Selecting max record for each user

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

This seems if it should be fairly simple, but I'm stumbling in trying to find a solution that works for me.

I have a member_contracts table that has the following (simplified) structure.

```
MemberID | ContractID   | StartDate | End Date |
------------------------------------------------
1          1              2/1/2002    2/1/2003
2          2              3/1/2002    3/1/2003
3          3              4/1/2002    4/1/2003
1          4              2/1/2002    2/1/2004
2          5              3/1/2003    2/1/2004
3          6              4/1/2003    2/1/2004
```

I'm trying to create a query that will select the most recent contracts from this table. That being the following output for this small example:

```
MemberID | ContractID   | StartDate | End Date |
------------------------------------------------
1          4              2/1/2002    2/1/2004
2          5              3/1/2003    2/1/2004
3          6              4/1/2003    2/1/2004
```

Doing this on a per-user basis is extremely simple since I can just use a subquery to select the max contractID for the specified user. I am using SQL server, so if there's a special way of doing it with that flavor, I'm open to using it. Personally, I'd like something that was engine agnostic.

But, how would I go about writing a query that would accomplish the goal for all the users?

EDIT: I should also add that I'm looking for the max contractID value for each user, not the most recent dates.

Comment: Are your date columns of type date or varchar?

Comment: They're of type date, but really, only the highest value for contract ID is what matters.

Comment: Are the contract IDs guaranteed to be unique?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This solution uses the uniqueness of the ContractId field:

```
SELECT MemberID, ContractID, StartDate, EndDate
FROM member_contracts 
WHERE ContractId IN (
    SELECT MAX(ContractId)
    FROM member_contracts 
    GROUP BY MemberId
)
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/599b2/1)

Comment: Nice, I was writing an answer that used `ROW_NUMBER`, but this is simpler and will work on versions for SQL Server previous to 2005

Answer (score 25):

The safest way to do this is with `row_number`

```
select MemberId, ContractId, StartDate, EndDate
from (select mc.*,
             row_number() over (partition by MemberId order by contractId desc) seqnum
      from Member_Contracts mc
     ) mc
where seqnum = 1
```

This handles the case of multiple contracts for the same member . . . which may not really be an issue in this data.

Comment: Awesome, this seems like the more general-case solution than relying on the contract ID being unique.  Any chance you'd mind elaborating on what your query is doing here?  In my case, I want to select the most recent record (as the title suggests); I put it into an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9dbd0/4) to demonstrate the most-recent behavior.